# XSD restriction based on xml content

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm new to XSD / XMl and was trying create a template for an xml file used in a project that I work with. The schema will be used by a couple of co-workers within visual studio and my main goal is to have the error checking and auto-complete features.

There is, however, one feature of my xml template that I would like to have on the XSD, but I don't know if that is possible. I think it isn't, but I just want to make sure.

Basically, the xml would look like this:

```
<root>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="@param1"/>
        <parameter name="@param2"/>
        <parameter name="@param3"/>
    </parameters>

    <test>
        <parameter_value parameter_name="@param1" value="whatever"/>
        <parameter_value parameter_name="@param2" value="whatever"/>
    </text>

</root>
```

The idea is that first the user "defines" the parameters, and then he assigns them values within a specific test. My question is weather or not I can define a restriction on the "parameter_name" attribute so that only declared parameters in this specific xml can be entered. Is this possible?

Best regards 
Carlos Jourdan

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in XSD 1.0. Typically something like this:

```
<xs:element name="root">
  <...>
  <xs:key name="paramName">
    <xs:selection xpath="parameters/parameter"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
  </xs:key>
  <xs:keyref refer="paramName">
    <xs:selection xpath="text/parameter_value"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@parameter_name"/>
  </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
```

This is from memory, so be prepared to look up the correct syntax in your favourite XSD text book.